# Why can't import ephem though it has been installed (Mac)?

Tags: python, pyephem

I have installed `ephem` on my computer. But I face a problem when I try to import it into my project.

`x-MacBook-Pro:~ dkfloza$ pip install ephem
Requirement already satisfied: ephem in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.7.6.0)`

I keep getting that the module doesn't exist. Any idea how can I fix that?

here is code:

```
import ephem
import datetime
## [...]

name = "ISS (ZARYA)";
line1 = "1 25544U 98067A   12304.22916904  .00016548  00000-0  28330-3 0  5509";
line2 = "2 25544  51.6482 170.5822 0016684 224.8813 236.0409 15.51231918798998";

tle_rec = ephem.readtle(name, line1, line2);
tle_rec.compute();

print(tle_rec.sublong, tle_rec.sublat);
```

Comment: Output of `pip --version`, `python --version`?

Comment: Can you add your code and the error you're getting to the question?

Comment: pipe --version : pip 18.1
python --version: Python 2.7.10 
@lagom

Comment: @najeem I have just edited the question

Comment: So, this is because your pip install module to python3, while you use python2. Please use python3 when import ephem.